# Where are the logs for Exchange 2010 stored?

Tags: email, log-files, exchange-2010

Where are the logs stored for Exchange 2010. Specifically error logs.

Cheers, Dean

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unlike Exchange Server 2003/2000, you have to enable logging separately for Send Connectors (used to send mail outside the Exchange organization, Send Connectors are equivalent of SMTP Connectors in Exchange 2003/2000), using the following command:

```
Set-SendConnector “Send Connector Name” -ProtocolLoggingLevel verbose
```

To enable protocol logging on a Send Connector using the EMC:

Expand the Organization Configuration | Hub Transport node
On the Send Connectors tab, select the Send Connector -> properties
On the General tab, change the Protocol logging level to verbose.

The logs can be found in

```
\Exchange Server\V14\TransportRoles\Logs\ProtocolLog\SmtpReceive
```

and

```
\Exchange Server\V14\TransportRoles\Logs\ProtocolLog\SmtpSend
```

Answer (score 1):

There aren't error logs per se. There are the event logs and if configured there are Message Tracking logs, Send connector logs, Receive connector logs, etc. What are you looking for?

Comment: I was looking for send connector logs. Would they be in the event log viewer or would it be an actual log file?

Comment: It's in a log file. You have to make sure that logging is enabled on the Send connector and then the logs will be at: C:\Program files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\TransportRoles\ProtocolLog\SmtpSend